# Error opening RawStream: Invalid sample rate [PaErrorCode -9997] google assistant SDK on RPi

Tags: linux, bash, python, raspberry-pi, api

I'm trying to install google assistant SDK on rpi by following this link 
"https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/run-sample"

While executing this command `googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id my-dev-project --device-model-id my-model`
I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/bin/googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py", line 351, in main
    flush_size=audio_flush_size
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/audio_helpers.py", line 190, in __init__
    blocksize=int(block_size/2),  # blocksize is in number of frames.
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 1264, in __init__
    **_remove_self(locals()))
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 780, in __init__
    'Error opening {0}'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 2572, in _check
    raise PortAudioError(errormsg, err)
sounddevice.PortAudioError: Error opening RawStream: Invalid sample rate [PaErrorCode -9997]
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was addressed and replied here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43958779/google-assistant-sdk-on-raspberrypi-3-sounddevice-portaudioerror

I tested the solution and it works for me as well.

Just change the `.asoundrc` to:

```
pcm.!default {
 type asym
 playback.pcm {
         type plug
         slave.pcm "hw:0,0"
 }
 capture.pcm {
         type plug
         slave.pcm "hw:1,0"
 }
}
```